# Remove a folder from Git

Tags: git

I have a local folder that is under git, when I was playing with some git stuff in different IDES, etc it got added to the git but I don't want it to be under git control, I just want it to be a normal folder for now! until I decide to add it to some repo later.

I am new to git so don't know much commands but if I run a `git status` command this is what I get:

```
git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .idea/vcs.xml
#   new file:   .idea/workspace.xml
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .idea/.name
#   .idea/.rakeTasks
#   .idea/HisFirstService.iml
#   .idea/dictionaries/
#   .idea/encodings.xml
#   .idea/misc.xml
#   .idea/modules.xml
#   .idea/scopes/
#   Gemfile
#   Gemfile.lock
#   README
#   Rakefile
#   client.rb
#   config/
#   db/
#   models/
#   service.rb
#   spec/
```

Comment: Which folder do you want to remove?  `.idea`?

Comment: You can create a file named `.gitignore`, which as its name suggests... Read more on the git manual ;]

Comment: @CarlNorum I am inside the HisFirstService  folder and these are all files inside that folder. So I want to remove HisFirstSerivceFolder from git control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you want to remove a git *repository* that was automatically created by an IDE. (Note that `git` doesn't track *folders*, only files.)

If that's the case, just remove the `.git` directory and you'll be left with a folder that isn't tracked by git at all.

Answer (score 7):

Use `git rm --cached` to remove this directory from repository (it should stay in your working directory) and then put it's name into .gitignore file. At the end commit both .gitignore and directory removal.

Comment: Full command is `git rm --cached -r <directoryNameOrPath>`. -r will run "recursive" and ensure the files in the directory are also removed from your git repository. Be sure to run the command from inside the git repository in question; for example if using the BASH shell and the git repository is inside /folder/repository, first use `cd /folder/repository` to move to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the terminal and have multiple files which are deleted to be removed from git, do this:

```
git status | grep [d]eleted | awk '{print $3}' | xargs git rm --cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that git does not store directories; it only stores files. This means that if you have committed any files from the subdirectory into your git repository, then you need to remove them with `git rm <filename>`. You also need to follow the instructions given by `git status` to remove files from the index. For example, `git rm --cached <filename>` will remove the new files so they will not be committed. Finally, you need to create a .gitignore file with the name of the directory which you don't want to have in your repo. This will make all future git commands ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named .gitignore and add the path of the folder you want to ignore (end with a "/").

Complete doc : https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files